# Discord greetings with cogs ,on_member_join , doen't work

Tags: python, discord.py

My `on_member_join` listener doesn't execute properly. The idea is that when a new person enters my discord, my bot greets them with a custom message.

There are no syntax errors and the class loads correctly. The `on_ready` listener responds correctly with `Welcome: ON`. If I try to do a debug print it is not executed.

Where am I doing wrong? I don't understand, it seems correct to me.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

class Welcome(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client=client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Welcome: ON")
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        guild= client.get_guild(828676048039706694)
        channel=guild.get_channel(828676048039706697)
        if channel is not None:
            await channel.send(f'Welcome {member.mention}.')

    @commands.command()
    async def Modulo_benvenuto(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send('')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Welcome(client))
```

This is my main file:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
        

client.run('TOKEN')
```

With a new bot it works, this is the code:

```
import discord
from  discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is on")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    
    print(member)
    await member.send("hello")

    guild = client.get_guild(831588406089744435) 
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, id=831588406089744438)

    if guild:
           print("guild ok")
    else:
        print("guild not found")

    if channel is not None:
        await channel.send(f'Welcome to the {guild.name} Discord Server, {member.mention} !  :partying_face:')
    else:
        print("id channel wrong")


client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Have you tried merging the two files/codes?

Comment: Nope, tomorrow i will try

Comment: nothing gives me this error: `TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***HOW TO FIX :***

**MAIN FILE**

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', intents=intents)
intents.members = True

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
        

client.run('TOKEN')
```

**COG FILE**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Welcome(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client=client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Welcome: ON")
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        print(member)
        await member.send("hello")
        guild = self.client.get_guild(831588406089744435)
        channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, id=831588406089744438)
        if guild:
            print("guild ok")
        else:
            print("guild not found")
        
        if channel is not None:
                await channel.send(f'Welcome to the {guild.name} Discord Server, {member.mention} !  :partying_face:')
        else:
            print("id channel wrong")

    @commands.command()
    async def Modulo_benvenuto(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('test')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Welcome(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `on_member_join()` event reference, you need the **Server Members Intent** privileged gateway intent to be on. This has to be done both in your bot's page as well as in your script (which you already have done):

1. Go to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).
2. Select the application and, under settings, navigate to *Bot*.
3. If you scroll down just a bit, you'll reach a section title **Privileged Gateway Intents** and, under that, *SERVER MEMBERS INTENT*.
4. Toggle the *SERVERS MEMBERS INTENT* to **ON**.

In the image below, it would be the second of the privileged gateway intents.

[image: Privileged Gateway Intents]

---

The issue with your code is likely because you have a `discord.Bot` instance defined in both your cog file as well as your main file. Since `setup(client)` is defined in your cog file and `client.load_extension()` is called in your main file, you should delete the following lines from your cog file:

**cog.py**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

However, to conserve the Intents, you'll want to add the following lines before your `discord.Bot()` call:

**main.py**

```py
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
```

---

For your code, I would recommend using the [`Client.fetch_channel` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_channel), since it eliminates the possibility that an incorrect Guild ID results in `channel` being `None`.

```py
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(1234567890)
    if channel is not None:
        await channel.send(f"Welcome {member.mention}.")
```

Or, you could just use `discord.utils.get()` and `member.guild.channels`:

```py
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, id=1234567890)
    if channel is not None:
        await channel.send(f"Welcome {member.mention}.")
```

Just a suggestion for reducing potential bugs.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I had already done both and it doesn't work anyway ...

Comment: Then, perhaps, the line in your code `channel=guild.get_channel(828676048039706697)` is returning `None`. If there are no error messages, then it's likely an issue where the `if` condition is not `True`. Verify that the guild ID and channel ID are correct, and, for debugging purposes, I would recommend putting an `else` statement and, inside the clause, just print something simple, like `print("Reached the else clause.")`.

Comment: I tried both versions of the function you wrote by adding else as well, but it doesn't send any welcome message and in console it doesn't print in else

Comment: What if you tried substituting the function body with `member.send("Hello")`? This should narrow it down to whether it's the event reference itself or the function body.

Comment: still nothing... ç.ç. I also checked the permissions of the bot and it has admin permissions

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because you have two files, each with its own `discord.Bot` instance. Try removing the lines starting from `intents =` and ending at `client =`, since you already have `client` defined in your main file.

Comment: Does your `Modulo_benvenuto` command work?

Comment: Should I change `client = commands.Bot (command_prefix = '.')` which is in my main.py with the three lines that are present in the cog? I'm confuse

Comment: quick question, you are working in cogs, but are passing "client" when clearly client has been declared as self.client (a class variable)? Is that a mistake or it's like that in the code itself? Because then it should error out as  " 'client' is not defined"

Comment: the code works, but the bot does not send the custom welcome message.

Comment: if I put those three lines in main.py it throws this error `client = discord.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'`

Comment: @Tμrf Oops, I forgot that `Bot` is in `discord.ext.commands`.

Comment: do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Tμrf Unfortunately not. I’ll continue to try things out and update you if I have any ideas.

Comment: @JacobLee i've found the solution. Anyways thank for ur time yesterday.